# Getting every record in one-to-many relationship in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, I've stripped out the information that is needless for my question so it is why they seem bare and pointless.

**Sessions**

```
SessionId (int) PK
```

**Answers**

```
AnswerId (int) PK
AnswerDetail (varchar)
QuestionNumber (int) 
IsCorrect (bit, null)
```

**SessionAnswers**

```
SessionAnswerId (int) PK
QuestionNumber (int)
SessionId (int) FK
AnswerId (int) FK
```

Imagine there are 10 questions, I want to have a row for each `Session`, and then each question and answer all in the same row. I.e. For each `Session` it should show me each question number and that session's answer.

Unfortunately, I haven't written SQL directly for a few years so I'm having a bit of difficulty getting it back up to scratch. I've so far managed to show this data, but it gives a new row for every answer that is provided by a session.

```
SELECT dbo.Sessions.SessionId, dbo.Answers.IsCorrect, dbo.Answers.QuestionNumber
FROM   dbo.Answers INNER JOIN
         dbo.SessionAnswers ON dbo.Answers.AnswerId = dbo.SessionAnswers.Answer_AnswerId INNER JOIN
         dbo.Sessions ON dbo.SessionAnswers.Session_SessionId = dbo.Sessions.SessionId
```

What should I be looking at to satisfy my aim? I'm not sure how to iterate through each `SessionAnswer` here

This is what I currently see:[image]:

But what I want to see is:

```
SessionId | Date | QuestionNumber1 | IsCorrect  | QuestionNumber2 | IsCorrect
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     | Date | AnswerDetail1   | IsCorrect1 | AnswerDetail2   | IsCorrect2
```

**I.E. Rows 1-12 in my picture should all be on the same row**

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a variable (changing) number of columns. One row for the session, then one column for each question and answer within that session, like a pivot table. This is very difficult to achieve in SQL-Server and would probably require quite a bit of dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 No, the number of columns is fixed.

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow. What do Question**X** and Answer**X** represent?

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 SessionAnswers.QuestionNumber and Answers.IsCorrect

Comment: Please show us an example of what you want.  Give some sample rows in your tables, the show us what results you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... now I understand. You need to perform a join, like you suspect, but you need to include the question number in the join. Then you need to repeat the join 10 times, once for each question. It's essential to use table aliases since you will be joining to the same two tables 10 times - you will need to be able to differentiate between each join.

```
SELECT      S.SessionId
        ,   A1.AnswerDetail AS AnswerDetail1
        ,   A1.IsCorrect AS IsCorrect1
        ,   A2.AnswerDetail AS AnswerDetail2
        ,   A2.IsCorrect AS IsCorrect2
        ,   A3.AnswerDetail AS AnswerDetail2
        ,   A3.IsCorrect AS IsCorrect2
        -- ...
FROM        Sessions AS S
-- Question 1
INNER JOIN  SessionAnswers AS SA1 
        ON  SA1.SessionId = S.SessionId
        AND SA1.QuestionNumber = 1
INNER JOIN  Answers AS A1
        ON  A.AnswerId = SA1.AnswerId
-- Question 2        
INNER JOIN  SessionAnswers AS SA2 
        ON  SA2.SessionId = S.SessionId 
        AND SA2.QuestionNumber = 2
INNER JOIN  Answers AS A2
        ON A.AnswerId = SA2.AnswerId
-- Question 3        
INNER JOIN  SessionAnswers AS SA3 
        ON  SA3.SessionId = S.SessionId 
        AND SA3.QuestionNumber = 3
INNER JOIN  Answers AS A3 
        ON  A.AnswerId = SA3.AnswerId
-- ...
```

*I rewrote this answer based on your update. To see the previous version, check the post history.*

Comment: I believe that this is what I currently already have. See my edit, am I still unclear?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the selected rows?
You can select hierarchical data [`FOR XML`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) and get an XML document that's quite easy to parse further.

So for instance

```
SELECT dbo.Sessions.SessionId, dbo.Answers.IsCorrect, dbo.Answers.QuestionNumber
FROM   dbo.Answers
INNER JOIN dbo.SessionAnswers ON dbo.Answers.AnswerId = dbo.SessionAnswers.Answer_AnswerId
INNER JOIN dbo.Sessions ON dbo.SessionAnswers.Session_SessionId = dbo.Sessions.SessionId 
FOR XML AUTO
```